# How to identify which instance is responding to a request on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a auto-scaling ruby on rails app on elastic beanstalk which occasionally has intermittent issues on one or more instances after deployment. This will result in a portion of the requests failing. If a request fails, I have no way of knowing which instance handled the request. Is there a way to know which instance has responded to a particular request, E.g. a way to add the ip of the responding instance in the header, or a way to search the load balancer logs?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of the load balancer logs?

Comment: Can you configure the health check on the load balancer to detect the intermittent issues and take the failing server out of rotation?